# What serializer to use (to xml) for circular reference and custom field?

Tags: c#, xml, reference, datacontract, circular-reference

I have the following xml:

```
<A name="">
    <B name="">
        <C name="">
            <B name=""/>
            <B name=""/>
        </C>
    </B>
    <B name="">
        <C name="">
            <B name=""/>
            <B name=""/>
            <B name=""/>
            <B name=""/>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Please notice that element C creates circular reference, so I can't use XmlSerializer.

How I can deserialize and serialize it?
It seems that I can't use DataContractSerializer because:

1. DataContract doesn't support attributes ("Name" in my example)
2. DataContract doesn't support ignoring outer element name, for example

   ```
   List<B> BList;
   ```

Will be serialized to:

```
<C name="">
    <BList>
        <B name=""/>
        <B name=""/>
    </Blist>
</C>
```

But I want too keep structure like in first example.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a circular reference if `C` has a reference to its containing object `B`. Is that the case?

Comment: There's no circular reference in the XML you show, to be more specific, it's impossible to describe a circular reference in XML, you can't create a child object which contains it's parent.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü yes

Comment: @Gusman I believe that such structure can represent logical tree, when each node can contain another node.

Comment: In XML you can describe different instances, you can't reuse the same instance to assign it to another item. Per example, the item "B" inside "A" is not the same item "B" inside "C", they are of the same type, but different instances, so there's no circular reference, to create a circular reference you need to use the same instances, and it's impossible in XML (and that's why XmlSerializer can't serialize circular references).
A tree is not a ring, a circular reference would be represented by some type of ring (instance a referes instance b, instance b refers to instance a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this with the help of XML Serializer and Deserializer

**Class Structure:**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "A")]
    public class A
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private List<B> b = new List<B>();

        [XmlElement("B")]
        public List<B> B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set { b = value; }
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private List<C> c = new List<C>();

        [XmlElement("C")]
        public List<C> C
        {
            get { return c; }
            set { c = value; }
        }
    }

    public class C
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private List<B> b = new List<B>();

        [XmlElement("B")]
        public List<B> B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set { b = value; }
        }
    }
```

**To fill Objects ( update this as per your requirement ) :**

```
private A a = new A();
        private void Load()
        {
            a.B.Clear();
            a.Name = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var tempB = new B();
                tempB.Name = string.Empty;
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    var tempC = new C();
                    tempC.Name = string.Empty;
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                        var innerChildB = new B();
                        innerChildB.Name = string.Empty;
                        tempC.B.Add(innerChildB);
                    }
                    tempB.C.Add(tempC);
                }
                a.B.Add(tempB);
            }
        }
```

**Serialization:**

```
private void Serialize()
        {
            try
            {
                // to Save columnorders to the file
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
                var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");

                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test_Jun13.xml"))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, a, ns);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

**Deserialization:**

```
private void DeSerialize()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"D:\Test_Jun13.xml"))
            {
                var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Test_Jun13.xml"))
                {
                    var obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    a = (A)obj;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }


    }
```

**XML File will look like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A Name="">
  <B Name="">
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
  </B>
  <B Name="">
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
  </B>
  <B Name="">
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
    <C Name="">
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
      <B Name="" />
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

will this fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about serializing / deserializing then you should use a serializer which supports circular ones, such as [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). If I am not mistaken [binary serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) should work as well.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate the reason for minus such that i can correct my answer

Comment: Json.net doesn't support circular references, no serializer supports them as I know, Json.net can "unwrap" the references but the serialized/deserialized object will not have the circular reference.

Comment: I was writing it.

Comment: @Gusman, yeah exactly like you said, When JSON.Net encounters the same instance in another place in the object graph, it simply drops a reference to the original instance,